# Shrink/Grow Div based on amount of data inside

Tags: xml, html

I have a 3 column, 2 row set of divs.
I want to make each div's heigh grow or expand based on the amount of data currently loaded inside. I am loading XML data into each of these 6 divs.

Anyone know how to make each div size correctly for height only. I am using css to set a specific width, but I''d like to make the height automatic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've almost answered your own question here. Unless I've misunderstood you can simply use:

```
div {
height: auto;
}
```

to ensure the height adjusts to the content within

Comment: I didn't realize there was such a thing.... my work uses a really old HTML editor and it wasn't one of the options....can't wait for the Adobe CS5.5 update we get in a few weeks. Thanks for your help!

Comment: No problem, the only thing to be careful of, is if your child content is marked as say 'float: left' but your parent container isn't. That way it jumps out of the normal flow and will not extend the parent item down with the childs content.

Answer (score 0):

You could clearfix the containing div, float the data left, add some padding around the data and set height to auto.